# Post tweet with net/http getting error in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am getting this error when i trying to post a tweet with the help of net/http in ROR. Please check the code and help me if any mistake I did. Below are my code

```
require "base64"
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "net/https"
require "uri"

### Setup access credentials

consumer_key = "consumer_key"
consumer_secret = "consumer_secret"

### Get the Access Token

bearer_token = "#{consumer_key}:#{consumer_secret}"
bearer_token_64 = Base64.strict_encode64(bearer_token)

token_uri = URI("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token")
token_https = Net::HTTP.new(token_uri.host,token_uri.port)
token_https.use_ssl = true

token_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(token_uri)
token_request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
token_request["Authorization"] = "Basic #{bearer_token_64}"
token_request.body = "grant_type=client_credentials"

token_response = token_https.request(token_request).body
token_json = JSON.parse(token_response)

access_token = token_json["access_token"]

### Use the Access Token to make an API request

timeline_uri = URI("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?screen_name= testingclient1")
timeline_https = Net::HTTP.new(timeline_uri.host,timeline_uri.port)
timeline_https.use_ssl = true

timeline_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(timeline_uri)
timeline_request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{access_token}"
timeline_request.set_form_data("status" => "your tweet")
timeline_response = timeline_https.request(timeline_request).body

timeline_json = JSON.parse(timeline_response)
```

It giving error on console

```
"code"= 220, "message"= "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."
```

Comment: you shouldn't post your access credentials like that. you'll want to change them now.

Comment: I was just saying that you shouldn't post your `consumer_secret` or `consumer_key` here. If those are connected to your account, I could take those and then tweet things from your account. You want to keep those private. I would go ahead and regenerate.